# How to bind variable in inline style in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, stylesheets

The code below shows binding of attribute in Lightning component.

```
<div style="{!'width:' + v.padAtr + '%'}">
</div>
```

Is there any way to do the same in LWC?
In LWC, i tried the below code and then passing "width: xxx%" from js. But it didn't worked.

```
<div style={padAtr}>
    </div>
```

Comment: Could your poste your javascript code also?

Comment: Im wondering if you still need to enclose it in quotes as well. I know normally you wouldn't for elements that come from the framework, but since this is a native HTML element, you may have to

Comment: When i save and deploy this: <div style={padAtr}>, it shows error and doesn't allow me to deploy it.I think its not the correct way. How can i replicate <div style="{!'width:' + v.padAtr + '%'}"> in LWC?

Comment: Are you sure it's not letting you deploy? What's the error message? I did the same thing for a project of mine and I get an eslint error in vscode but the deployment itself succeeds.

Comment: @JohnTowers I just tried and the deployment was successful. The styling also works fine. But it still shows error while hovering to it.

Answer (score 2):

The error you're getting is from vscode's CSS validator. `style={padAtr}` works in LWC but it violates a rule in the CSS validator that vscode runs.

If you don't need/use the validator and you want to get rid of the errors, you can disable the validator entirely by going to `File > Preferences > Settings > Extensions > CSS` and unchecking the `Validate` checkbox. Otherwise you'll have to find the specific rules being violated and disable them.

As far as I can tell, you can't disable rules for a specific file or ignore a specific line, so whatever you disable will be disabled for all files.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the replacement for expressions in LWC is using JS Getters.

I would try adding the following to your component and seeing if that works.

```
get styleAttr() {
    return `width: ${padAttr}%`;
}
```